# A conditional to show if a entry has a playa parent or has entry in another channel with category?

Tags: conditionals, categories, playa

Sorry for the convoluted question. Let me add some clarity to this:

I have a two channels: products & videos. On the videos channel I have custom field for a YouTube url along with a Playa field to relate the video to a specific product(s). I also tied the same category group the products channel is using to the video channel. I have this setup for two reasons:

1. Client can add a video to a category so this video is shown on all products pages with that category
2. Client has the option to relate the video to a specific product(s)

I realize I could potentially just use the Playa filter to get the correct entries and do a mass dump but I thought it would be a lot easier to just use a category if the video is a general overview of a certain product category.

How do I structure the conditional to show/hide if a video matches those options?

I'm using the awesome [URL Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper) addon for segment variables so I can easily do something like this on the single product page:

```
{exp:channel:entries
   category="{segment_2_category_id}"
   channel="videos"
   disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
   dynamic="no"
}
    show video stuff
    {if no_results}no video here{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

or use the Playa tag `{exp:playa:total_parents}` in a conditional. The problem is I need to check both before displaying the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I figured it out! I had to buy [Entries Number](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entries-number) add-on. This allowed me to find/search if any entries were tied to a certain category and return a number. Take note of the `{segment_2_category_id}` variable, this variable is from the URL Helper add-on I mentioned above. You could potentially use `{segment_category_ids_any}` to do an inclusive search also–which I'm using b/c I have true nested URI's `domain.com/products/parent_cat/sub_cat/entry`

```
{if {exp:playa:total_parents channel="videos"} > 0 || {exp:entries_number category="{segment_2_category_id}" channel="videos"}{entries_number}{/exp:entries_number} > 0}
    has video
{/if}
```

I'm still curious to see if anyone has any other solutions.